# Exception handling in Spring Boot Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception

I'm trying to handle exceptions in a spring boot application that has SOAP endpoints and Rest controllers.

Catching exceptions that occur in the rest controller is quite straightforward, I just set a class with @controlleradvice that has @exceptionhandler methods and all exceptions get caught. However, this controlleradvice doesn't seem to catch exceptions that occur in the SOAP endpoints. Is there a way to catch the exceptions that are thrown in the endpoints on a @controlleradvice class? If not, is there some other way to centralize exception handling throughout the entire application, independently from where the exceptions are thrown?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You would need to post the code, but in general, this is usually caused by the fact the exception was not thrown from inside a bean, so it is not in Spring world.

Comment: Could you please post the code so that we can analyse the problem...If you want to catch all the exception's then catch throwable in ExceptionHandler @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class) but in general this is not advisable also you can specify array of exceptions you want to catch in @ExceptionHandler so what would i think is the exception you would like to catch is not part of the class you defined in ExceptionHandler...We can easily sort it out if you post the code...

Comment: I need to have some place in my application in which I can catch any exception that may be thrown anywhere in the code. My application has REST and SOAP entrypoints. I found that ControllerAdvice is a nice way to catch exceptions thrown in a controller. But this ControllerAdvice only catches exceptions thrown in the REST controller entrypoint, the ones thrown on SOAP endpoint aren't catched. I think that's because ControllerAdvice listens for Controller classes and Endpoint isn't a Controller. Is there a way to catch the exceptions thrown in SOAP endpoint in my ControllerAdvice class?

Comment: Like you have mentioned , `@ControllerAdvice` works well with `@RestController`. I used `@Aspect` to get the same effect on `@Endpoint` SOAP controllers.

Answer (score -1):

We can create customized exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) public class StudentNotFoundException extends 
RuntimeException {}
```

Exception handler in Spring:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends 
ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
@ExceptionHandler(StudentNotFoundException.class)
 public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> 
 handleUserNotFoundException(StudentNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
  ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
  request.getDescription(false));
 return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}


public class ErrorDetails {
private Date timestamp;
private String message;
private String details;

public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
  super();
 this.timestamp = timestamp;
  this.message = message;
  this.details = details;
 }
```